# iAds on iOS app not working properly

Tags: ios, iad

Hi i have uploaded a free app to the appstore.

Here is the itunes link for the app

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/travelr/id666234375?ls=1&mt=8

Its a Lite version app. So i have integrated iAds. when i test my app with the simulator it works fine. it shows the Testing Add.

I have set up the iAd Settings in iTunesconnect.

When i view the status for the iAds its showing as "Live ads" and currently i have 67 request and my Fill Rate and iAd Fill Rates are 0.00 %

I have two uncleared Questions

1. When i downloaded the app from the appstore its still showing the Test Add on my device.
2. Some people canot see the iAds. (iAds is showing in my device but in my friends device i cant see iAds).

Can any one help me?

Comment: Where, exactly, are the ads in your app?

Comment: i Have integrated iAds in 2nd Tab (Currency Converter View)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This happens because you are viewing the app on your provisioned device.  This is normal.

2) iAds will only display if there is inventory.  This is also normal.  It's your job to handle this with the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

So for instance you may need to resize or move content depending if the ad banner is visible or not.

Comment: Hi berry thanks for your reply. Any way I am not doing any thing with Adbannerviewdelegate bcoz I am using apple's Bannervirwcontroller class. So every thing is handle by that class. 

From your point now I realize that tests ads are shown In provisioned device.. 

Other than provisioned device add Is not shown?

So is this a problem with my coding?

Comment: If you are seeing test ads your code is fine.  I'm not sure why you think that ads not showing up on some devices is a problem.  It's up to Apple whether or not your ad banner shows an ad at any particular time on any particular device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm downloading your app, so I'll have a definitive result here pretty soon.

In my experience, however, if an app is set up correctly in iTunes Connect, and it's status is set to Ready for Sale, you will get iAds.

Sometimes it's just a bit weird on development devices.

Comment: Thanks for you help. In my iTunes Connect iAd network page i can see the status as Live Ads. is this mean that iAd is successfully integrated? and also i have 70 Requests.. but my fill Rate and iAd Fill rate is 0.00 %

Comment: @user If you wait a week and you get no revenue, you probably need to worry. Otherwise, let your app work its way into the system.

Comment: its just 4 days my app got approved, still i didnt get any revenue.. Is this because of development problem ? i have already sent a message to Apple... waiting for their reply

Comment: @user It could be, but if you are seeing test ads it's highly unlikely. About how many downloads has your app had so far?

Comment: It's a great app, by the way. Nice blue tint.

Comment: @user 8 units isn't much - wait until you get several hundred users and you should start seeing revenue come in.